# Called data from parent page to nested page

Tags: php, ajax, xml, rss

I am calling data from a dropdown menu on a php page to nested php page using ajax.  I am able to populate the dropdown menu from a database but I am unable to use the corrisponding database data beyond echoing them.  I am attempting to make the nested php page display a website based off of the database referenced in the dropdown on the parent page.

Inside of the console I am receiving ReferenceError: showUser is not defined. for rss.php

rss.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="rss.php">
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['uname'] . "</option>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="rssOutput">RSS Display</div>
</body>
</html>
```

getrss.php

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

//get the q parameter from URL
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

$id = $row['id'];

$xml = $row['info2'];


$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='" . $channel_link
  . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
}
?>
```

Could this potentially be a problem with how the url drawn from the database table is displayed I would think not as I imagine its displayed rather literally.  I am using a general wamp server.

Comment: So your `users` dropdown bind to `showUser` on-change, but there is only a `showRSS` function in your post. Is that intended?

Comment: Ba-Da-Bing, that worked.  Gratzie good sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `users` dropdown is bind to `showUser` on-change, but there is only a `showRSS` function in your post. Unless that is intended, changing your code to use `showRSS` should work.

```
<select name="users" onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
```